# How to make loop smaller in Tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I would like to know how I could make my loops smaller/less high? Because at the moment they take up too much space on the page.

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
i \arrow[r,"\alpha"] & j \arrow[out=120,in=60,loop,"\beta_1"]
 \arrow[out=240,in=300,loop,swap, "\beta_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: Please put the code in your questions rather than pictures, so people can copy and paste it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with help of `looseness=...` from TikZ I reduce upper loop:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
i \arrow[r,"\alpha"] & j \arrow[out=120,in=60,loop,looseness=3, "\beta_1"]
 \arrow[out=240,in=300,loop,swap, "\beta_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use just the `loop above`, `loop right`, ... keys without worrying about the details.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
i \arrow[r,"\alpha"] & j \arrow[out=120,in=60,loop,"\beta_1"]
 \arrow[out=240,in=300,loop,swap, "\beta_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}
i \arrow[r,"\alpha"] & j \arrow[loop above,"\beta_1"]
 \arrow[loop below, "\beta_2"]
 \arrow[loop right, "\beta_3"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```